# Transaction when inter-communicate microservices

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, akka, microservices

I'm looking for best approach to keep data consistent while inter-communicate between microservices in my project.

Project built with Jersey + Guice and uses Akka to glue services in whole system. I use separate transaction across call to another service to avoid long-running transactions. I use Hibernate as ORM and Postgres as DB.
Process looks like:

1. Begin transaction
2. Do some work
3. Commit transaction
4. Call to another service using Akka, receive or send some data
5. Begin transaction
6. Do remaining work
7. Commit transaction

So if step 4 failed my data becomes in non consistent state. I spent some hours to find solution to avoid it but I was failed. Is there some right way to keep it in consistent state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to avoid long-running transactions, but want to have a logical equivalent of them which is still (possibly) long-running, then you are effectively pushing the "transaction" abstraction to the application level.

The simplest solution is to just accept that and invent some column for your data indicating that the records are dirty, then make them non-dirty in step (6).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I had such idea but how to recover data from this state? Each request starts from step 1 and can't be started from step 5.

It seems I need some cron that will continue remaining work or something like that.

Comment: Data is just data. Logic is in your code. If you want retries of your whole process then you can code such logic: in cron, a microservice separate from your original requests or whatever.


The difference between original idea of transactions and my proposition is that for errored "processes" (let's call a run of steps 1-8 a process), in the former case you wouldn't have data in the database at all, in the latter case you will have dirty records. This may be good, because you would have a chance to retry them. If you want it.


Hard to say what's best for you without more detailed info..

Comment: i think that good choice would be to use some kind of messaging system (service bus, rabbit mq, etc) where mechanisms like repeating work, async communication are build in so u don't have to reinvent the wheel by yourself. U could try read about sagas which is some known approch. when u switch to messaging mostly all u care about is to publish messages in right order to create kind of workflows. Repeat work is as simple as rescheduling message back to queue.

Answer (score 0):

Microservice sagas could be helpful here. More details on [Sagas](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)